# Definition of the space $C^{\beta}(I,X)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ an interval and $(X,||\cdot||_X)$ a Banach space. Give $1<p\leq\infty$, we define the [Bochner Spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space) $L^p(I;X)$ as being the set of all functions Bochner mensurables $u:I\to X$ such that the corresponding norm is finite:

$${\displaystyle \|u\|_{L^{p}(I;X)}:=\left(\int _{I}\|u(t)\|_{X}^{p}\,\mathrm {d}t\right)^{1/p}<+\infty {\mbox{ for }}1\leq p<\infty ,}$$and
$${\displaystyle \|u\|_{L^{\infty }(I;X)}:=\mathrm {ess\,sup} _{t\in I}\|u(t)\|_{X}<+\infty .} $$

**My question:** Let $0<\beta<1$, can I define $C^{\beta}(I,X)$ in an analogous way? If so, what does $||u||_{C^{\beta}(I,X)}$ mean?

Comment: What would you mean with a $C$ instead of a $L$?

Comment: @Mindlack, in the Hölder space sense.

Comment: Oh, okay. Then, you could simply define $C^{\beta}$ as the space of all functions $I \rightarrow X$ that are $\beta$ -Holder (hence continuous!) with respect to $\|\cdot\|_X$. A natural choice for $\|u\|_{C^{\beta}}$ would be $\|u\|_{\infty}+\sup_{x \neq y \in I}\,\frac{\|u(x)-u(y)\|_X}{|x-y|^{\beta}}$. Or maybe I misunderstand you?

Comment: Thank you @Mindlack. I was confused by what could be the norm.